# Derivation of linear equation for minimizing quadratic polynomial of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

In the material of a course I am following, the following derivation is given.

[image from course material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mFoD.png)

I tried to follow along with the calculations, but I struggle with expanding the factors in the form

$$||AB+C||^2 $$

with

$$ A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$$
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $C$ must be $3\times1$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lVert AB+C \rVert^2 = (AB+C)^T(AB+C) = (B^TA^T+C^T)(AB+C) = B^TA^TAB + \dots
$$